# HttpServletRequest getParameter of Radio Buttons

Tags: java, servlets, radio-button

I want to have the parameter value of radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="Official"/>Official Only
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="lang" value="all"/>All
```

How do I check in java to see which one is selected?

Comment: Also verify the form method type - POST or GET. If it is POST then override doPost and if it is GET then override doGet method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` with the name of the input field as parameter name.

```
String lang = request.getParameter("lang"); // Can be null, "Official" or "all"
```

The value of the input field will become the parameter value.

```
if ("Official".equals(lang)) {
    // Official selected
} else if ("all".equals(lang)) {
    // all selected
}
```

Comment: From there would I just say if(lang.equals("Official")) ?

Comment: Yes, just the usual Java way. Be aware of `null` though.

Comment: Then it's `null` (i.e. nothing has been selected, or you used the wrong name, or they aren't in the form at all). Just do a `if (lang != null)` beforehand, or go ahead with the example in my updated answer.

Comment: I have quadruple checked and I am still getting a nullpointerexception even when I check if lang is null

Comment: Then the way how you checked it is wrong, or the way how you interpreted the NPE is wrong, or you aren't running the code you think you're running. Hard to tell based on the information given as far. First this: do you know/understand when a NPE will be thrown?